# How to hide a slider on form submit in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, slider, submit, hide

I am using a jQuery plugin to display a slider on my page, I want to hide it when the user presses the search button (Submit Form).
How can I do this ?
Code for calling Slider:

```
 <!-- Initialize the csstubeslider plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#gallery").csstubeslider();
    });
</script>
```

My html:

```
   <div id="gallery"><a href="#" class="show">
<img src="images/slider/s1.jpg" id="slideimg" />
</a>
<a href="#" <img src="images/slider/s2.jpg" id="slideimg" />
</a>
```

Here is the form:

```
 <form class="searchform" action="webpage.php" method="POST">
<input class="searchfield autosuggest" type="text" name="name"  placeholder="Search for a name " onFocus="if (this.value == 'Search...') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search...';}" />
<input class="searchbutton" type="submit" name"name" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$('body').on('submit', '#formID', function(){
    $('#gallery').hide();
});
```

Comment: I have tried but its not working, I have added the form code in the question for reference.

Comment: And you used `.searchform` as the selector? Are you aware that `<a href="#" <img src="images/slider/s2.jpg" id="slideimg" />` isn't valid code by the way?

Comment: can you explain why its not valid ?

Comment: Because you can't just open a new tag within another one, you should close your anchor link first, use: `<a href="#"> <img src="images/slider/s2.jpg" id="slideimg" />
</a>`

Comment: Anyway I fixed my issue but placing an if statement in php and using display:none.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to submit on this form using jquery like this:

```
$('.searchbutton').submit(function() {
    $("#gallery").hide(); // hides the gallery 
    // alternative way: $("#gallery").css("display","none");
});
```